# Elements appears differently on mozilla & chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, cross-browser

Please be kindly to open this site http://goo.gl/0LdOVK on both mozilla & chrome. You'll notice there's a slight difference on header & footer widgets (the search & subscribe form)

I really have no idea what causes that. Please help! :(

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem or a sreenshot

Comment: I dont have both browsers, screenshots (and code) would be nice. Also consider the fact that Chrome and Firefox have different for example offsets. Some take a border inside the element, others outside the elemt. Maybe specify certain rules in your CSS when you create elements you know will end up differently in both browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set the width you need need it to be in firefox and other browsers like Internet Explorer, then just target chrome to edit the width of the input field using:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    /*Chrome CSS here*/

    .input[type="search"]{

         width: 231px !important;

    }

}


/* For other browsers */
.input[type="search"]{

    width: 210px;

}
```

So set the width of your input field to be 'width: 210px;'

Then  use the @media screen code above to target chrome and set it to the width you want on there. A possibility?

Comment: Thank you very much joshbrown! it works perfect! I wish I could vote up your answer :/ have a great day!